Application of adjunction similar to properties of exponent theory
the following link: https://www.math3ma.com/blog/what-is-an-adjunction-part-3, discusses this property: if $X, Y, Z$ are sets then $X^{Y \times Z}\cong(X^Y)^Z$ holds, the proof of this result is by adjunction. This looks like a property of exponent theory $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ where $x,y,z$ are numbers. My question is: is there any other property of exponent theory, which holds for sets and can be demonstrated with adjunctions? I thought that maybe the following could be proven: $(X\times Y)^Z\cong X^Z\times Y^Z$. I hope for some suggestion, thank you very much
Regards

Hint: $-^Z$ is a right adjoint, and right adjoints preserve limits.
